# How to remove extra summary tag in Visual Studio XML comments for XAML files?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, sandcastle, xml-documentation

I'm seeing two summary tags in the generated XML documentation for WPF files. One comes from the code behind file as expected. The other appears to be auto-generated by the compiler as it seems to come from the .g.cs file.

Any idea how to remove the second one?

To reproduce (in VS2012):

1. Create a new WPF application from the template.
2. On the project's properties for Build, check XML documentation file.
3. Build.
4. Look in the generated WpfApplication1.xml file.

I see this:

```
<member name="T:WpfApplication1.App">
    <summary>
    Interaction logic for App.xaml
    </summary>
    <summary>
    App
    </summary>
</member>
```

This ends up in Sandcastle generated documentation as:

> Interaction logic for App.xml
>   App

Thanks!